# Built-in functions vs library-called functions

Tags: function, python-3.x, libraries

I just started learning Python and I have some confusion about using built-in functions when you have the ability to call functions from libraries and why do you even have built-in functions in the first place when you have libraries?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please elaborate us your effort showing the necessary part of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Balance between namespaces and convenience.

The built-in functions are considered generally useful to the point where they are available by default; it would be a royal pain to need to import a module just to use the `str` or `int` constructor after all.

The built-in modules/packages (requiring an `import` to access) are considered less generally useful; avoiding the expense of loading them when they're not needed, and namespacing them to avoid cluttering the global namespace with tons of names people may want to use for other purposes is generally a good design pattern.